# Big O notation for inverse exponential algorithm

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

Let's say you had an algorithm which had n^(-1/2) complexity, say a scientific algorithm where one sample doesn't give much information so it takes ages to process it, but many samples to cross-reference made it faster. Would you represent that as O(n^(-1/2))? Is that even possible theoretically? Tldr can you have an inverse exponential time complexity?

Comment: It would be easier to answer your question if you could show some code/pseudo-code which quantifies the `O(n^1/2)` behavior to which you are referring.  Can you add code?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: the OP doesn't mean +1/2 but -1/2 !

Comment: @YvesDaoust That almost half makes sense to me `:P`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: what ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define O(n^(-0.5)) using this set:

O(n^(-0.5)) := {g(n) : There exist positive constants c and N such that 0<=g(n)<=cn^(-0.5), for n > N}.

The function n^(-1), for example, belongs to this set.

None of the elements of the set above, however, could be a an upper bound on the running time of an algorithm.

Note that for any constant c:

if: n>c^2 then: n^(-0.5)*c < 1.

This means that your algorithm do less than one simple operation for input large enough. Since it must execute a natural number of simple operation, we have that it does exactly 0 operations - nothing at all.

Comment: So really it'd be O(1) unless at a certain point it did nothing at all

Comment: O(1) means the number of simple operation done is bounded by some constant C. O(n^(-0.5)) says that the number of operation done by your algorithm is bounded by the constant *zero*. This is a lot stronger than O(1). In that case, although O(1) does provide an upper bound, it is a weak upper bound, and a tight upper bound is always better. And just to clear things out - There is no real algorithm whose running time is bounded by zero! This discussion is pure math.

Answer (score 0):

A decreasing running time doesn't make sense in practice (even less if it decreases to zero). If that existed, you would find ways to add dummy elements and increase N artificially.

But most algorithm have at least O(N) complexity (whenever every data element influences the final solution); even if not, just the representation of N gets longer and longer which will eventually increase the running time (like O(Log N)).